# Getting single record in Oracle/ Oracle APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm building a page in APEX. In that page I have 2 items, "text field with autocomplete" Both of them are getting the LOV from the same table but different column.  text_field_1 getting the id_1; text_field_2 getting the id_2

So If I input/select a value from text_field_1 I can set a value automatically to text_field_2  or vice versa.  I can do one is to one relationship, like if I enter "bca" in text_field_2, I can set the correct value for text_field_1 which is "2"

But I'm having a problem for the one is to many relationship. If I enter "1" in text_field_1, It will return 2 values which are "abc,cba" I'm trying to figure it out on how I list the abc and cba so that I can still choose what value I want from the two.  Please someone help me with this?

This is my sample table

| id_1 | id_type_1 | id_2 | id_type_2 | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | employee_id | abc | employee_code | 01-01-1000 00:00:00 |
| 1 | employee_id | cba | employee_code | 02-01-1000 11:00:00 |
| 2 | employee_id | bca | employee_code | 01-01-1000 12:00:00 |
| 3 | employee_id | acd | employee_code | 01-02-1000 14:00:00 |

Thank you so much in advance. I really need this

Answer (score 0):

If you use list of values, then that's exactly what its name says - a **list** of **values**. They are supposed to return more than a single row, that's perfectly normal and expected situation.

Therefore, your LOV1 (which is a "source" of e.g. `P1_ITEM_1`) should

```
select distinct id_1 as display_value,
                id_1 as return_value
from your_table
```

while LOV2 would then have `P1_ITEM_1` as a **parent LOV item** and

```
select id_2 as display_value,
       id_2 as return_value
from your_table
where id_1 = :P1_ITEM_1
```

---

To answer what you asked:

> if I select id_1 = 1 then I will get the 'abc' OR if I select the other id_1 = 1, I will get 'cba'

Can you do that? Sure; the question is which one of `abc` or `cba` you want. What we usually do is to select *any* of them using `min` or `max` aggregate function, e.g.

```
select max(id_2)
from your_table
where id_1 = :P1_ITEM_1
```

(you'd get `cba` as a result in this case).

Comment: oh I see but If I use the aggregate function like max in the LOV  then I will never get the abc right?

Comment: In this case, you won't. But, if you use MIN (in this case), you will. As I said: LOV's purpose isn't to return only one row as a result. It is a **list**, and users will have the opportunity to pick any value they want (actually, any value your query returns so it is you who decides which values are valid).